# Var renderTemplate function issue - client-side handlebars issue

Tags: javascript, html, gruntjs, bower, handlebars.js

My apologies, but, I've not found an answer that resolves my issue. I'm a noobie to handlebars, and can't figure out from the forums how to resolve the following error message. I'm trying to add an edit feature to a list for an html5 mobile app taken from a video tutorial. Handlebars seems to want a string, but I'm not sure of where Im supposed to pass this string. The error I keep getting is: **Uncaught Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile.** You passed undefined. I feel like the renderTemplate function is incorrect because I'm missing parens and the pound sign. However, when I try and add the parens and the # tag targetTemplate I continue to get the Uncaught error. Can someone clarify whether or not it's the parens/# or some additional step that i'm missing. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. I didn't provide the full html but I will if you need it to get a better understanding.

```
<script id='full-list-template' type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="list-group">
            {{#each beers}}
            <a data-item={{id}} data-target="#item-detail" href="#" class="list-group-item view-switcher">{{title}}</a>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </script>


    <script id="item-detail-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <h3>Add Item</h3>
        <div class="list-group">
            <p id="show-title" class="list-group-item">{{title}}</p>
            <p id="show-description" class="list-group-item">{{description}}</p>
            <p id="show-image" class="list-group-item">
                <span class="label">Image</span>
                <img src="">
                </p>
            <p id="show-location" class="list-group-item">Current Location: Lat {{location.latitude}}, Long {{location.longitude}}</p>
        </div>

        <p>
            <button data-target="#full-list" id="back-to-list" class="btn btn-lg-default view-switcher">Back to List</button>
            <button data-item={{id}} data-target="edit-item" id="edit-item" class="btn btn-lg-default pull-right view-switcher">Edit</button>
        </p>
    </script>
    <script id="add-item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <h3>Add Item</h3>
        <form id="add-form" role="form" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" type="text"> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <button id="transcribe" class="btn btn-lg btn-info pull-right">Transcribe</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <button id="upload-photo" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right">Upload A Photo</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p><strong>Current Location: Lat 37, Long 122</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button data-target="#full-list" id="cancel-add-item" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-left view-switcher">Cancel</button>

                <button id="submit-add-item" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </script>

<script id="edit-item-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <h3>Edit Item</h3>
        <form id="edit-form" role="form">  
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{id}}" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="title" name="title" type="text" value={{title}}> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title">Description</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description">{{description}}</textarea> 
            </div>
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <button id="transcribe" class="btn btn-lg btn-info pull-right">Transcribe</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                <button id="upload-photo" class="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right">Upload A Photo</button>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <p><strong>Current Location: Lat 37, Long 122</strong></p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button data-target="#full-list" id="cancel-add-item" class="btn btn-lg btn-default pull-left view-switcher">Cancel</button>

                <button data-target="#full-list" id="edit-item" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </script>
```

Here's the MAIN.JS file:

'use strict';
var beers;

```
//functions
var hideShowFunction = function(evt){
    var eventTarget = $(evt.target);
    var data = eventTarget.data();
    $('.view').removeClass('active');
    $(data.target).addClass('active');

    renderTemplate(data.target, data.item);
};

var renderTemplate = function(target, itemId) {
    var targetTemplate = target + '-template';
    var source = $(targetTemplate).html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    // var data = {beers: beers};
    // var data = {title: 'This is the title', body: 'This is the body!'};
    // actual data!
    var data;
    if (itemId){
        var arr = $.grep(beers, function(beer, i){
            return beer.id == itemId;
        });
        data = arr[0];
    }
    else {
        data = {beers: beers};
    }
    var html = template(data);
    $(target).html(html);

};

$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

var saveEntry = function(result) {
    var highestId = Math.max.apply(Math, beers.map(function(o){return o.id;}));
    result.id = highestId > 0 ? highestId + 1 : 1;
    beers.push(result);
    localStorage.beers = JSON.stringify(beers);
};

var editEntry = function(result) {
    var resultInt = parseInt(result.id);
    result.id = resultInt;
    for(i in beers) {
        if (beers[i].id === resultInt ) {
            beers[i] = result;
            localStorage.beers = JSON.stringify(beers);
            break;
        }
    }
};

// event listeners
$('body').on('click', '.view-switcher', function(evt){
    hideShowFunction(evt);
});

$('body').on('submit','#add-form', function(evt){
    var result = $(this).serializeObject();
    saveEntry(result);
    renderTemplate('#full-list');
    return false;
});

$('body').on('submit','#edit-form', function(evt){
    var result = $(this).serializeObject();
    editEntry(result);
    renderTemplate('#full-list');
    return false;
});

//storage
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
    if (localStorage.beers){
        beers = JSON.parse(localStorage.beers);
    }
    else {
        beers = [];
    } 
}
    else {
    console.log('does not work');
}

// call render template (init) 
renderTemplate('#full-list');
```

Comment: I think targettemplate needs to be this: var targetTemplate = '#' + target + '-template'

Comment: What do you get if you put `alert(source);` just before `Handlebars.compile(source);`?

Comment: C.O., my list is no longer visible when I use '#'.; S.A. when i use alert, I get the same response through grunt as I do with the hash tag. Doesn't work. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your item-detail-template the submit button is missing a # sign in the data-target

```
<button data-item={{id}} data-target="#edit-item" id="edit-item" class="btn btn-lg-default pull-right view-switcher">Edit</button>
```

I just started doing this same video tutorial and am stuck in the same spot. My problem is that I can't get the localStorage to save my edit. I signed up to create a question for this. Found your question before I made my own. I hope this helped answer even if it is a year after you posted :)